# Failed to connect to Safari driver through Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, grid, safaridriver

Getting the following exception when trying to run the selenium tests on Mac- Safari using Selenium Grid. I could see the  safari browser on Hub console, but when running the tests getting the exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10357 ms

Safari Extension version : 2.48 and 
Selenium Stand alone server : 2.53
```

Code:

```
DesiredCapabilities ds = new DesiredCapabilities();
ds.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "safari");
ds.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "MAC");
```

Could anyone help/guide me in resolving the issue

Comment: My first guess would be that the browser name is case sensitive, given that the error message is using "Safari" and not "safari".

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Selenium_Grid
{
       WebDriver driver;
       String baseUrl, nodeUrl;

       @BeforeTest
       public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException
       {
           baseUrl = "www.fb.com/";
           nodeUrl = "http://192.168.1.57:6666(port_n0)/wd/hub";
           DesiredCapabilities capibility = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
           capibility.setBrowserName("safari");
           capibility.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
           driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capibility);

       }

       @AfterTest
       public void tearDown()
       {
           driver.quit;
       }

}
```

Try with this-

Note:

1. use proper parameters that you have used in your code.
2. check whether node is successfully connected or not with your Hub.
3. use different port no of Hub & node.

Comment: @Swapna, Have you tried with this ?